# Switch focus to new browser tab once it is opened

Tags: javascript

I the below script, once the button is pressed, a new browser tab with Google is opened. I then want to fill the search box on this newly opened tab.

How do I switch focus to this new tab, so that I can wait for it to load completely and then fill the search box?

```
<button id="start">Google</button>  

<script>
    function open_google_in_new_tab() {
        var url = "https://www.google.com";
        window.open(url);
        window.onload(fill_search_box()); // here it will try to operate on the old tab
    };

    function fill_search_box() {
        var search_box = document.getElementsByName("q")[0];
        search_box.value = "Some text";
    };

    var start_button = document.getElementById("start");
    start_button.addEventListener("click", open_google_in_new_tab);
</script>
```

Comment: This cannot be done with JavaScript but you can configure your browser to immediately switch to new tabs when they are opened

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly target another element in another document from your script, however, you can set the textbox value of the Google textbox using a query string:

```
www.google.com?q=SearchTerm
```

When creating the SearchTerm you should also use `encodeURI` to ensure that your attached search query meets URL standards

Also, if you wish to open the window in another tag you can use `window.open(url, "_blank")` to open.

See example below:

Note:- The page will not open due to snippet restrictions - so run in your own browser.

```html
<button id="start">Google</button>

<script>
  function open_google_in_new_tab() {
    var text = "Some text";
    var url = "https://www.google.com?q=" + encodeURI(text);
    console.log(url)
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  };

  var start_button = document.getElementById("start");
  start_button.addEventListener("click", open_google_in_new_tab);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Please see my comment for holydragon's response, I think it also applies here.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with Javascript unfortunately.

However, this might make you achieve something similar if you are willing to try.

You can manipulate the search string via parameter named "q" in the query string of the Google website. So, in order to make the user to go the Google and search this particular word, you attach the keyword to it. Something like this:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com?q=searchKeyword";
```

Comment: Thanks. My real use case is more complicated though. I thought I could switch tab focus mid-code, so that for example some actions are performed in newly opened tabs, and the original tab writes what has been done into a HTML table. I can do something similar through VBA - iterate through Windows shell and intercept Internet Explorer tab by its name.